# Why use hexadecimal in ASM?

Tags: assembly, hex

I couldn't seem to find an answer to this, and it's really starting to bug me.
Is this simply because a hexadecimal value consists of 4 bits? (Assuming second operand would be an integer otherwise - point out if I'm incorrect)

```
mov   ebx,0x00   ; why not ebx,0?
mov   eax,0x01   ; why not ebx,1?
```

The above seems to work with both when making a system call to `sys_exit(0)`, hence my confusion asto why use hexadecimal if it's easier to do it the other way.

Comment: for consistency for one thing, personal preference of the author

Comment: Code conventions, tradition.

Comment: A hexadecimal value consists of exactly the same number of bits as the same decimal representation. That's no different.

Comment: It's easier to express some numbers is hexadecimal. Let's say unsigned 2^64-1... It's is `0xffffffffffffffff`, but in decimal... I really don't remember. As for `0x00`, `0x01`, those are probably for consistency and code conventions.

Comment: Great responses from everyone above, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good practice to use whatever base makes sense for a given context.  Much of what you're doing in ASM is dealing with registers, memory addresses, etc. which are conventionally notated in hex.  Spend some more time in assembly and see if you still think base 10 is "easier."

Comment: I was thinking that it might be used differently depending on context, although, I wasn't certain.
I know hexadecimal is much easier on larger values; I meant in my situation: where the values are small.
Thanks for your answer.